# Portamento only when gate already opened

Tags: synthesis, reaktor

In the factory synth, [Oki Computer](https://www.native-instruments.com/en/reaktor-community/reaktor-user-library/entry/show/3525/), there is a portamento/glide knob. I would like to alter the instrument so that a new note (ie. the gate has closed) begins on it's default pitch rather than pulling the pitch from the previous note.

It looks like this would be done in the `gate pitch > mono` module:

[image: mono module of Oki Computer]

or perhaps within the `gate pitch > mono > glide` itself:

[image: glide module]

The portamento goes away when I remove the (highlight) cable between the GI output and the Glide GI input and am thinking maybe some kind of use of a Compare module will do the trick.

### Update

First of all, I realized that I can achieve the musical goal in this case simply by manually manipulating the *amount* of portamento with the knob, turning it down for non-legato lines. However, I aim to make sense of the wonderful answer to this question anyway.

Based on the input from answer below, I am working on building the various version of this module. The first thing I realized is that *portamento* happens between the pitch input and the sound generation. So it goes:

`pitch input` > `portamento` > `oscillators`

There's a tutorial [here](https://www.adsrsounds.com/reaktor-tutorials/creating-a-reaktor-glide-effect-with-mike-huckaby) by Mike Huckaby, which demonstrates putting the pitch input through a `1 pole filter`, and converting the `low-pass` output from the filter from `analog` to `event` data, while using a `control` (knob) to generate the input on the `1 pole filter`, which might step (as in this example) by increments of `1` between `-60` and `60` Hertz (mostly below the audible range).

You get something that looks like this:

[image: basic monophonic portamento]

So I think that perhaps for the "Monophonic Legato-Only Portamento" approach it would be inserting the "Single Trigger Gate>Separator>Hold>Selector" module, something like this, but I don't know *what* is coming out of the selector module, how to tell what is coming out of it, or what it is supposed to feed.

[image: Monophonic Legato-Only Portamento attempt]
(Selector input should be around `128`, not `0`.)

The `AllKeyGate` macro from accepted answer works nicely.

Attempting now to implement the Portamento macro that implements is, including a pitch filter:

[image: Implementing the All Key Gate module]

Not sure if I have all of the connections correctly from the image below:

[image: Maybe the portamento module]

Comment: I assume you mean that you want portamento when playing legato style and no portamento when leaving gaps between the notes? Are you using it as a monophonic or polyphonic synth?

Comment: @YourUncleBob it's monophonic. Or at least the monophonic mode of Oki Computer that I am playing with. From what you guys are saying, I am wondering if Reaktor is the wrong animal for this part.

Comment: One thing I'm curious about is, is there a term to describe `portamento when playing legato style and no portamento when leaving gaps between the notes`?

Comment: @piiperi If you build your own Single-Trigger Gate, the simple trick of temporarily setting the portamento time to zero at the start of non-legato notes seems to result in useful polyphonic legato portamento.

Comment: I deleted my comment about legato being difficult to do, because there are many different cases of monophonic and polyphonic instruments. Suffice it to say that the Single-Trigger Gate module does not work like you'd expect it to work, and you need to work around it.

Comment: The P input in the filter is pitch (MIDI note numbers), not frequency (Hz). A range of -60 to 60 corresponds to approx. 0.25 Hz to 261 Hz. You should add an OR module after the Separator so that every positive event is converted into a value 1, and set the constant for the Selector to something like 128 (because a higher filter frequency means a shorter portamento time). Btw, if you hold the mouse over a wire, the current value going through it is displayed. You can also display values in the instrument panel by attaching e.g. a Lamp to it, and setting the lamp's numerical value to "visible".

Comment: @YourUncleBob Getting back to this again after a few aborted attempts over the last few months. I plan to select your answer as "correct", once I have finally implemented it and confirmed that it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a **monophonic instrument**, or a polyphonic instrument with the number of voices set to one, you can use simple tricks to get legato-only portamento to work. Here's one such solution, which temporarily sets the portamento time to its minimum value at the start of non-legato notes:

[image: Legato portamento (version 1)]

You start with the *Single Trigger Gate* module, which creates a gate signal of all keys/voices combined, which means that it doesn't send a new key-on event when playing legato. You set both its minimum and maximum output value to 1, so that every key-on event has a value of 1 whatever the velocity is.

You then use a *Separator* module to filter out the key-off events, and use the key-on events to trigger a *Hold* module with a very short time, e.g. 1 millisecond. You then use the output of the *Hold* module to select between the time setting for the portamento, and a constant time value (indicated in red in the image) that is low enough so that the new pitch is reached within the 1 millisecond that you've set in the *Hold* module.

The end result is that whenever you play a note after a gap, the portamento time is set to its minimum setting so that the pitch jumps to the new note instantly, and then the portamento time is set back to its original setting.

Depending on how the portamento module or macro is programmed, you may have to adapt the *Hold* module time and the alternative low time setting for the portamento to get the desired result. If you use a *1-Pole Low-Pass Filter* module on the pitch signal as portamento, then a filter pitch of 128 is high enough to jump five octaves without noticeable glide. A higher filter frequency means a shorter portamento time. So that's a number that you might use for the bottom input on the `Selector` module (in red, above).

---

The method described above also works to an extent for **polyphonic instruments**. You can play monophonic non-legato lines without portamento, and legato lines and chords with portamento. You can also set the *Hold* module time to something like 100ms, and then you can play non-legato chords without portamento.

Depending on whether you set the *Voice Assign* in the instrument's properties to "Newest" or "Oldest", you'll get slightly different results.

There are some anomalies, e.g. when you set a long portamento and release time, play a few notes that are still changing pitch during their release phase, and then play another note, the new note will cause all the notes to suddenly jump to their final pitch. This can be fixed with the version below, which combines the *Single Trigger Gate* module output with each voice's own gate signal:

[image: Legato Portamento (version 2)]

This still leaves some problems, caused by the *Single Trigger Gate*, which doesn't function as you'd expect when playing non-legato notes while holding down one or more keys. Of course, as always in Reaktor, we can just build our own, which behaves the way we want it to; combining *Selective Note Gate* modules, we can make a monophonic gate macro that keeps track of every key on the keyboard, independent of the instrument's polyphony:

[image: All-Key Gate Octave]

The above macro combines twelve *Selective Note Gate* modules, to keep track of the keys in one octave; combining multiple of these macros gives us a complete all-key gate:

[image]

If you replace the *Single Trigger Gate* module by the above *All-Key Gate* macro in the version with the combined monophonic and polyphonic *Hold* modules, with a hold time of around 50 ms, you have a useful polyphonic portamento. As before, setting the instrument's *Voice Assign* to "oldest" or "newest" will give slightly different results.

---

When you use the *1-Pole Low-Pass Filter* module to create portamento, there is the additional complication that the Pitch signal never quite reaches its target, and all notes are slightly flat or sharp, depending on whether the pitch gradually changed from a lower or a higher note. (In an instrument which requires exact pitches, such as an FM synth with seperate portamento settings per operator, this could be problematic; in other instruments it may be less noticeable.)

This slight pitch offset depends on the filter frequency and the note number. However, if we shift the pitches to the range 128 ~ 255 before the filter and then subtract 128 again after the filter, the offsets are the same for all notes:

```
Filter     Note
Pitch     Offset

  48     ±0.0004    (fast)
  36     ±0.0008
  24     ±0.0016
  12     ±0.0033
   0     ±0.0065
 -12     ±0.0131
 -24     ±0.0262
 -36     ±0.0524
 -48     ±0.1048    (slow)
```

Below is a portamento macro which compensates this offset, to produce precise pitches. It also incorporates the legato portamento functionality, using the All-Key Gate macro described above.

[image: Legato Portamento macro with offset compensation]

It has four inputs:

- P (Pitch) in MIDI note numbers: 0 ~ 127 (polyphonic)
- G (Gate) note off: 0, note on: 1 ~ 127 (polyphonic)
- T (Time) portamento time: 0 ~ 127 (monophonic)
- H (Hold) time in ms: 0 ~ 127 (monophonic)

When the portamento time is set to 0, the filter is bypassed, to avoid any hint of portamento. When the Hold time is set to 0, portamento is applied to every note; when Hold time is set to 1, portamento is only applied to legato notes; a higher setting, around 50 or so, allows all notes in a chord to be considered non-legato, even when the keys are not pressed at exactly the same time.

The constant value 60, which is merged with the Pitch input, provides an initial key value; the first notes you play after loading or restarting the instrument will rise or fall from this note number; it can be set to any value from 0 to 127. The constant value 43 sets the time range to approximately 0.01 ~ 10 seconds for a 5-octave glide; increase or decrease this value to have shorter or longer portamento times.

The output of the portamento macro is an audio-rate signal; for the smoothest results, don't convert it to an event-rate signal, but connect it to the F (frequency) input of oscillators (with an Exponential Pitch to Frequency conversion module between them), and connect a constant value of -276.478 (which corresponds to 0 Hz) to the oscillator's P (pitch) input. Note that other pitch modulation (pitch bend wheel, LFO, envelopes, ...) should always be added to the pitch signal after the portamento.

Comment: In your first example, what is the source of the `portamento` module?

Comment: @MikeiLL I deliberately didn't show the portamento macro, because this should work with any portamento module or macro that has an input for time or speed. The idea is simply to temporarily set the time to its lowest (or speed to its highest) value at the start of each non-legato note.

Comment: Is the all-key gate macro available somewhere in the NI user library? I think I considered such a contraption, but gave up on the idea after figuring out there would have to be 128 x something. My working solution used a poly-gate to single-trigger gate thingy, but IIRC its note tracking ability was limited by the polyphony in that instrument. So the actual instrument has to be "fake mono".

Comment: @piiperi I don't know; I enjoy tinkering and coming up with my own solutions, so I rarely look at the user library. Only the note number in the *selective note gate* module has to be set manually every time; the rest is just clicking *duplicate*. And a range of 12 - 108 is more than enough.

Comment: You deserve some kind of a medal for this stuff. ️

Comment: Working my way to understanding this, I have added an update to the question.

Comment: @YourUncleBob the AllKeyGate module is working very nicely. In the `portamento` module, 1. is `T` going into the `minus` as well as the `or` to it's right? 2. Is the `pitch/stpFlt` going to `up/down` as well as `+128`? 3. Is `128` going into `+` as well as `-`? Updating my question with images.

Comment: @MikeiLL 1. Yes (otherwise there'd be no point in the minus module). 2. Yes, the Step Filter output goes to the Pitch Up/Down macro, the Add module and the Selector module. 3. Indeed; you add 128 to the signal going into the filter, then subtract it again afterwards.

Comment: @YourUncleBob With the implementation in my above images, a Portamento time of `0` is producing no output whatsoever. Higher settings produce really low pitches on the keyboard and stranger intonation: a major 3rd between F and C, a major second between C and G, etc...

Comment: @MikeiLL Oops, I forgot to mention that the output of the portamento macro (P) is of course a pitch signal (i.e. a note number), so you have to run it through an Exponential Pitch to Frequency module before connecting it to the F input of an oscillator.

Comment: @YourUncleBob I should know that by now. Still not doing what I want, though. Now every key seems to generate the same frequency, which is so low it sounds like ticks when the `p` input on the oscillator is `-276.478`, and gets more tone-like around `30`.