# Shift Phase of LFO Wave

Tags: synthesis, reaktor

I'm using this module to create percussive patterns with the LFO:

[image: Noise module front panel]

As you can see the frequency can be synced with the clock of the host DAW:

[image: Reactor modules of the LFO section]

What I'd like to be able to do is to shift the phase of the LFO so that the user could, for example, shift between this:

[image: LFO phase in sync]

and this:

[image: LFO phase shifted]

Horizontal bars represent steps in the host sequencer.

I believe that "sync" might come into play here, and my understanding of sync would be that when implemented, the start of the LFO wave begins again with every new pressing of the key.

### Update

There is a `sync` input, which, when creates a button control you can set to "toggle".

And a `SyncPhase`, which I would expect does what I want. It says that with values between -1 and 1, the phase can be shifted between `-180` and `+180` degrees.

[image: The Sync Phase controls in the module]

[image: LFO Panel with sync controls]

However I am still unable to shift the phasing of the amplitude around the sequencer steps as I want to.

Even stepping away from the DAW clock. I would expect that, with

- `sync` toggled to "on" (`min:1, max:1`)
- LFO amplitude at max (`1`)
- Pulse wave operating on amplitude

That with `SyncPhase` at either `-1`, `0`, or `1`, the "on" phase of the amplitude LFO would occur when the gate opens (pressing the keyboard).

It's seems as if `sync` isn't engaging at all.

## update

As per the (soon to be) accepted answer below, I have updated the way the LFO module is configured so that it's output is multiplied with the oscillator output (as opposed to receiving it at the `A` input).

[image: New configuration of LFO module]

And implemented the recommended module, with the LFO `amp` knob going from `0` to `1`.

[image: Implementation of solution]

However I'm still not getting what I want, where I can shift so that the "on", or `1` phase of the LFO is concurrent with gate opening. Like I would think that

- with `sync` toggled on,
- frequency setting very slow
- Amplitude at `1` (all the way on)
- if I press a key repeatedly without sustain
- while turning the `syncPhase` knob
- it will shift between *always* and *never* making a sound
- in other words between [silent-sound-silent-sound] and [sound-silent-sound-silent]

But it still isn't doing that.

Comment: Is the `SyncPhase` setting also available when the `Source` is set to `Clock`?

Comment: Yes, @Tom_C. It is. And that makes me realize that the feed for the `knob` input on the switch should not be multiplied by the `clock`. However the problem is still there. I cannot seem to `SyncPhase` shift so that the #on# phase occurs upon gate open.

Comment: (Wild guess, I am not using Reaktor): are you sure Reaktor is able to dephase a square wave? If this phase is implemented as a biais value, you have effectively a phase change for a Sin, but not for a square…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sync inputs of the various oscillator and LFO modules expect an audio signal or another signal that alternates between negative or zero and positive; when the signal changes to positive, the oscillator is retriggered.

The easiest way to sync an oscillator to the MIDI clock is to use the `Sync Clock` module. Its output alternates between a value that you can set in the properties (e.g. 1) and zero, and you can select whether it follows the clock in 1/4 notes (beats) or 1/8, or 1/16 ...

[image: Reaktor structure]

In this example the `Sync Clock` signal is multiplied with the value of the `Sync` button which toggles between 1 and 0, to switch the synchronization on or off.

[image: Reaktor panel]

You also have to take into account that the output of oscillator and LFO modules varies between +A and -A. If you want to use the output to modulate the amplitude of an audio signal (i.e. multiply it with the audio signal), set A somewhere in the range 0 ~ 0.5, and add 1 - A to the output. This will result in the output varying between 0 and 1 if A is set to 0.5, and a fixed output of 1 if A is set to 0. (Output marked with `x`)

If you want to use the output to modulate the pitch of an oscillator or filter (where a value is alternately added and subtracted from a center value) don't add anything to the output of the LFO (output marked with `+`). You can multiply this output further down the line, before adding it to a pitch signal, to set the depth of the modulation effect.

---

If you want the LFO to run at the same frequency as the clock, but sync it to the key presses, you could add another `switch` module to select between the `Sync Clock` and the `Single Trigger Gate` as the source of the sync signal.

[image: Reaktor structure]

Then you can set the tempo of the LFO to either the MIDI clock or manually with the panel knob, select the sync source independently, and use the `Sync Phase` knob to select which part of the LFO waveform you want to start with when a key is pressed or the MIDI clock changes to positive.

[image: Reaktor panel]

If this is used in a polyphonic instrument, the `Single Trigger Gate` may not behave as you want it to, in which case you could replace it by either the regular polyphonic `Gate` module (and make the whole LFO macro polyphonic) or the `All Key Gate` macro from [my answer about portamento](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/88311/14836).

Comment: I believe I have recreated your example. 1 Source is between `Tempo Info` and `Freq`. 2. `Amp` knob from `0` to `0.5`, divided by 2 and split to `A` input of LFO, then subtracted from `1` and re-added to LFO output. 3. This (`x`) output is multiplied with output from a noise osc. RESULT Following the `1-A` the connection reads as `inactive`.

Comment: @MikeiLL I'm only dividing by 2 because the knob goes from 0 to 1 (that seemed more logical as a user interface). If the knob goes from 0 to 0.5, you don't need to divide it. The `inactive` problem sounds like a mixed mono/poly problem; make sure you don't have poly signals feeding into mono modules.

Comment: Updated the question with my implementation. The cause of `inactive` was having assumed that the output that was higher up _inside_ the module corresponded to the higher one _outside_. I had named them with the same first few letters. However, out outlined above, it still doesn't seem to work as desired.

Comment: @MikeiLL When you talked about syncing and the MIDI clock, I assumed you wanted the LFO synced to the clock. As I understand it now, you want it to have the same frequency as the MIDI clock, but sync it to the key presses?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The highlighted LFO is used to sync the signal of the other LFOs. By adjusting the width of the square wave, i can adjust the timing it syncs the main LFO.

This solution did **not** work when i skipped either of the "compare/equal" or "A/E" modules. If you make it exactly as the highlighted modules, it should work.

A delay module could also be used for it, but ive been up all night, so my brain refused to do the math to get it to sync up with the BPM and rate :S